# Derived to base implicit pointer type conversion

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, polymorphism

For a generic tree structure, I'm using some code that looks like this (The following code is a MCVE):

```
template <typename T> class Base {
protected:
  Base() {}

public:
  T *ptr;
  void setRelated() { ptr = this; }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.setRelated();
  return 0;
}
```

**Rationale**: The reason for doing this is to save the developer using this class the effort of having to cast everything around from base to derived and back for every call and algorithm used in this class, especially that the base is abstract and can't be instantiated by itself.

This code doesn't compile. It says:

```
main.cpp:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘Base<Derived>*’ to ‘Derived*’ [-fpermissive]
   void setRelated() { ptr = this; }
                   ~~~~^~~~~~
```

**The question**: Is there a way to make all conversions from `Base<Derived>*` to `Derived*` implicit (assuming we shouldn't overload every method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... especially that the base is abstract and can't be instantiated by itself.

You cannot make `Base` abstract directly. That needs to derive it from another
class (interface) that specifies the pure virtual functions<sup>1</sup>.

---

> Is there a way to make all conversions from Base* to Derived* implicit (assuming we shouldn't overload every method)?

No, there isn't.

The typical idiom for the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is to use a `static_cast`:

```
 void setRelated() { ptr = static_cast<T*>(this); }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Take a look at [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/) where I was using that technique extensively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if `setRelated` has the pointer as parameter? I'm finding myself in a position where I have to provide 2 overloads (one for `Base<Derived>*` and another for `Derived*`. Is this the only way?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist AFAIK that is the only way to deal with it. The problem is aka _Static Polymorphism_

Comment: To your edit: I didn't mean abstract by having a pure virtual function. I meant abstract just by making it non-instantiatable without inheritance. It's the same effect, except that no methods to be overloaded.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You mean the `protected` constructor? Yes that will have the same effect regarding instantiation, but will not make the base class _abstract_ in the sense of the common usage of that term. ATM I can't tell if you're chasing a XY problem without given more background about your actual use case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Protected constructors aren't covered by the std. The specification seems to say that protected member functions can't be constructors, or something.